# Omit a column while writing mysql data into a csv file using fputcsv

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli

My code for fetching mysql rows and write to csv file using fputscv is working fine. But I want to omit first column while writing to the csv file. Clearly telling, all the fetched values are different points of a graph and I would be directly importing that generated csv file for a graph generating code. The id (which is not a graph point) will be included in csv file if I use a query like,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mybase WHERE id='$id'";
$qry = $dbo->prepare($sql);
$qry->execute();
$row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);       
fputcsv($data, $row);
```

Anyone knows the best method to eliminate the ID before writing into the csv file.?

I  saw an obvious and simple result [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123508/how-to-skip-some-fields-from-database-while-using-fputcsv). Unfortunately, I have too many columns and it is difficult to specify each column in sql query. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `UNSET` it like

```
unset($row['ID']);
fputcsv($data, $row);
```

Orelse You can fetch all the columns except `ID` in your query itself like

```
$sql = "SELECT other_than_ID_column FROM mybase WHERE id='$id'";
```